# R - Filtering data by a composed condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets view the following code:

```
u_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5)
i_id <- c(10, 10, 10, 12, 10, 11, 13, 13, 13, 10, 11, 13, 13, 14)
clicked <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)

dframe <- data.frame(u_id, i_id, clicked)
```

which creates the following data frame:

```
   u_id i_id clicked
1     1   10       0
2     1   10       1
3     1   10       1
4     1   12       1
5     2   10       0
6     2   11       1
7     3   13       0
8     3   13       0
9     3   13       1
10    4   10       0
11    4   11       1
12    5   13       0
13    5   13       0
14    5   14       1
```

I want to filter the data in the following way:

For the same u_id, i_id:

1. if theres only 0 (one or more) in `clicked`, leave it so.
2. if theres 0 (one or more) and 1 in `clicked`, delete all rows with 0 in clicked (the row with the 1 in `clicked` remains)
3. if there are multiple rows with 1 in `clicked`, preserve only one row (the first or what ever)
4. if there are 0 (one or more) and multiple rows of 1 in clicked, delete all rows with 0 and preserve only one row with 1 (still doesnt matter which one)

After applying all of the above rules we should get:

```
   u_id i_id clicked
3     1   10       1
4     1   12       1
5     2   10       0
6     2   11       1
9     3   13       1
10    4   10       0
11    4   11       1
12    5   13       0
13    5   13       0
14    5   14       1
```

I left the original row index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution in base R using a split-apply-combine approach:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dframe, list(dframe$u_id, dframe$i_id)), function(i)

    if (sum(i$clicked) == 0) {

        i

    } else {

        i[i$clicked == 1,][1,]

}))
```

Result:

```
        u_id i_id clicked
1.10       1   10       1
2.10       2   10       0
4.10       4   10       0
2.11       2   11       1
4.11       4   11       1
1.12       1   12       1
3.13       3   13       1
5.13.12    5   13       0
5.13.13    5   13       0
5.14       5   14       1
```

Comment: You can split by both columns like `split(df, list(df$u_id, df$i_id))` and avoid the extra column

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Sotos. I'll edit to incorporate.

Comment: You can also use `by` that returns list of dfs: `by(df, df[c("u_id", "i_id")], FUN=...` (no `lapply` needed).